# How do I change font color in Lua?

Tags: fonts, lua, coronasdk

I am new to Lua, using Corona, and I am having trouble figuring out how to change the font color.
 `color = { 163, 25, 12 }` doesn't work.

```
myButton = widget.newButton{
        id = "open_id",
        left = 12,
        top = 360, 
        label = "open",
        fontSize = 16,
    font = "Helvetica Neue Bold",
    color = { 163, 25, 12 },
        width = 294, 
        height = 40,
        cornerRadius = 2,
        onEvent = onButtonEvent
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
myButton = widget.newButton{
    id = "open_id",
    left = 12,
    top = 360, 
    label = "open",
    fontSize = 16,
    font = "Helvetica Neue Bold",
    labelColor = { default = { 163, 25, 12 }, over = { 163, 25, 12} },
    width = 294, 
    height = 40,
    cornerRadius = 2,
    onEvent = onButtonEvent
}
```

See:

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newButton.html

Comment: Widgets are not really intended for that.  If you need to do something like that, I would consider an image with a touch handler that you can do a :setFillColor() on.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.coronalabs.com/reference/index/widgetnewbutton

labelColor
table. This table should hold the red, green, blue, and alpha channels for the color of your label in both its 'default' and 'over' states. Here's an example table:
{ default={ 128, 255, 96, 255 }, over={ 0 } }